# Display filenames of selected files - asp:fileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I have an asp file upload which AllowMultiple = "true" enabled. how do I display the filenames of the selected files of the user?

Comment: what have you done ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
protected void uploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (UploadImages.HasFiles)
   {
       foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in UploadImages.PostedFiles)
       {
         uploadedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"),
           uploadedFile.FileName)); 
         listofuploadedfiles.Text += String.Format("{0}<br />", uploadedFile.FileName);
       }
   }
}
```